# Failed to add edge detection runtime error

Tags: python

```
from gpiozero import Button
btn = Button(4)
while True:
    print("begin")
    btn.wait_for_press()
    print("Pressed")
    btn.wait_for_release()
    print("Released")
```

This code worked at first but now I get runtime error:

```
failed to add edge detection.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What have you done between the time it worked and the time it stopped working?

Comment: are you running the code as root?

Comment: @MohammadAli The code should not need to be run as root.

Comment: @joan yes but it seems be the thing that he could most likely be doing differently from when his code originally worked